# Select Into Multiple Object with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know, how to achieve this using LINQ:

Object:

```
 public class ObjView
    {
      public A aObj { get; set; }
      Public B bObj { get; set; }
    }
```

Query:

```
var query = from a in A
            join b in B on a.B_Id equals b.B_Id 
            select new ObjView(){
            aObject.Item1 = a.Item1,
            aObject.Item2 = a.Item2,
            bObject.Item1 = b.Item1,
            bObject.Item2 = b.Item2,
            };
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], there are too many parts missing from this question to fully understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: What happens when you try the code you have?

Comment: This seems like a bit of an XY problem - it's very unusual to want to split  things into different objects.

Comment: Any reason not to just have a sensible constructor on `ObjView` which takes in your `A` and `B` and creates the `ObjView` as you want?

Comment: It will not only throw a null reference exception, but also it will not compile, cause you've used your property names incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ObjA> objAs = new List<ObjA>();
        List<ObjB> objBs = new List<ObjB>();

        var query = (from a in objAs
                     join b in objBs on a.ID equals b.ID
                     select new ObjView()
                     {
                         ObjA = new ObjA()
                         {
                             Item1 = a.Item1,
                             Item2 = a.Item2
                         },
                         ObjB = new ObjB()
                         {
                             Item1 = b.Item1,
                             Item2 = b.Item2
                         }
                     });
    }
}

public class ObjA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Object Item1 { get; set; }
    public Object Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class ObjB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Object Item1 { get; set; }
    public Object Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class ObjView
{
    public ObjA ObjA { get; set; }
    public ObjB ObjB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Answer should not be a question ;)

Comment: @Marco yes, that is what I want to achieve.